# Is it possible to mix Eve (Python) Mongo schemata and Eve SQLAlchemy schemata?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, eve

I want to create an API which on one side can use the normal mongodb interface for storing documents but on the other side access user data which is stored in a SQL database.

Therefore: Is it possible to mix Eve Mongo and [Eve SQLAlchemy](https://eve-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) schemata as illustrated below?

```
DOMAIN={
    'people': People._eve_schema['people'],
    'data': data,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, currently that's not possible since you can either use the default mongo data engine *or* switch it with the Eve-Sqlalchemy engine.